# React JS table with filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to adapt this table found here in the react js docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html#step-1-break-the-ui-into-a-component-hierarchy)
and ran into some strange issues as seen in the screenshots below. 
[image]

We try to filter on lBir

[image]

And the end result is I get extra rows. Here is the code in all its glory.

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
  
  class UserRow extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const user = this.props.user;
      const name = user.name;
  
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{name}</td>
          <td>{user.system}</td>
        </tr>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class UserTable extends React.Component {
    render() {
      const filterText = this.props.filterText;  
      const rows = [];  
      this.props.users.forEach((user) => {
        console.log(this.props.users);
        if (user.name.indexOf(filterText) === -1) {
        //   console.log('filter text = -1')
          return;
        }
        rows.push(
          <UserRow
            user={user}
            key={user.name}
          />
        );
      });
  
      return (
        <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>system</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>{rows}</tbody>
        </table>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class SearchBar extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleFilterTextChange = this.handleFilterTextChange.bind(this);
    }
    
    handleFilterTextChange(e) {
      this.props.onFilterTextChange(e.target.value);
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <form>
          <input
            type="text"
            placeholder="Search..."
            value={this.props.filterText}
            onChange={this.handleFilterTextChange}
          />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }
  
  class FilterableUserTable extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        filterText: ''      
    };
      
      this.handleFilterTextChange = this.handleFilterTextChange.bind(this);
    }
  
    handleFilterTextChange(filterText) {
        console.log(filterText);
      this.setState({
        filterText: filterText
      });
    }
    
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <SearchBar
            filterText={this.state.filterText}
            onFilterTextChange={this.handleFilterTextChange}
          />
          <UserTable
            users={this.props.users}
            filterText={this.state.filterText}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
  
  
  const USERS = [
    {name: 'lJames', system: 'test@testy.com'},
    {name: 'lJames', system: 'test@tester.com'},
    {name: 'lBird', system: 'lbird@moretesting.com'},
    {name: 'mJordan', system: 'lbird@somemore.com'},
    {name: 'tester', system: 'mjordan@nba.com'},
  ];
  
  ReactDOM.render(
    <FilterableUserTable users={USERS} />,
    document.getElementById('container')
  );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is added to the
      homescreen on Android. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

I can see in the console the following warning: 
"Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `lJames`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version."

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Array filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React uses keys as a way to identify components within a list, and they should be unique within that list [(React docs)](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys). If there's more than one component with the same key it can lead to issues like the one you're seeing (since you're using `name` as a key, and two users have the name `lJames`).

You can fix this by either giving each user a unique `id` property, or use the concatenated user and email as a key - `key={user.name + user.system}`

Answer (score -1):

**Apply filter on any table using React**

Ex:-
1. First you need State to store all data

```
state = {
  List: [],
  backupList: []
};
All data should be stored in List[]. And backupList[] is needed for reference
which acts as temporary variable.
```

2. Make a Input box of type *text* and use *onChange* event.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Filter" onChange={this.filterList} />
```

3. Make a method named *filterList*

```
filterList = (event) => {
var updatedList = this.state.backupList;
updatedList = updatedList.filter(function(list) {
  return (
    list.fullname.toLowerCase().search(event.target.value.toLowerCase()) !==
    -1
  );
});
this.setState({
  List: updatedList
});
};
```

Here, I am filtering table based on **Fullname**, but you can use this method for different data.